# Mule- Behaviour-Driven Development using JBehave

Tags: mule, bdd, jbehave

Is it possible to use JBehave for BDD testing in mule application? Any working example will be very helpful.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

should be possible. What do you want to test? It's easy to test a single Java Transformer with JBehave, but it's getting worse when you start writing integration tests with JBehave. Seriously I won't do that.
It could work if you use MUnit with Java, but I would never ever mix Java JBehave stuff with XML MUnit tests because it will become unmaintainable.

I always test without a BDD tool as wrapper and use simple Given-When-Then-like syntax as names of my tests. For example: "should-be-irrelevant-when-purchaser-is-zero" is a name of one of my test. By using this you always see which test fails why.

looking forward to your response

Comment: So you are saying it is only possible to test java component with JBehave ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to test a custom Java transformer like this one:

```
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer;

public class MyCustomTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {
    @Override
    protected Object doTransform(Object src, String enc) throws TransformerException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It's definitely possible, but I don't see why it should be a benefit. I would use Mockito with Given/When/Then syntax instead.